# Using TinyCC (tcc) to generate a C wrapper for V

Tags: c, binding, tcc, vlang

I am trying to find some basis I can use to generate wrappers/bindings for C libraries to be used from [Vlang](https://github.com/vlang/v) and whilst doing so, I remembered that initially, V uses TCC for it's bootstrap compilation.

Since TCC is a very, very capable C compiler, I wondered if it was possible to utilize this and make this a way to generate wrappers and bindings by using TCC's built in parser/lexer to generate a symbol table of structs, functions, enums and the like and then iterate over said table to generate V code.

Judging from reading `tcc.h`, the API described here is usable, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was declared internal and thus not fully documented. Where can I find more information about how I could use TCC as a plain parser?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've already found some information regarding this, but for posterity, here are some places with information about TCC and using it as a dynamic code generator:

1. [The TCC Git Repo](https://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git)
2. [The Gnu project page](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc/)
3. [The TCC Development Archive](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/tinycc-devel/)